# How to supply Jacoco agent to an Android app?

Tags: android, maven, jacoco

I am trying to get code coverage using Jacoco for manual testing. I am trying to use offline instrumentation. http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html

In there it mentions:
**Configuration File:** If a file `jacoco-agent.properties` is supplied on the classpath options are loaded from this file.

My question is how do I supply this? On some other forum, I saw that `jacoco-agent.properties` needs to be deployed with the app.

I tried putting `jacoco-agent.properties` under the res/raw, but it complained about "-" in the file name.

I tried putting this under the root directory it didn't take any effect.

I was wondering how could I setup\run jacoco so that it uses `jacoco-agent.properties`?

Comment: You should also note which IDE you are using.

Comment: I was trying to do this from command line using maven.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574594/install-resource-file-into-root-of-apk just put these resources in src/main/resources

Answer (score 3):

Well, at least for an Ant command line build the trick was to put `jacoco-agent.properties` in the `src` directory, which makes it get packaged as-is into the root of the APK file, from where it seems to be properly read (i.e. I can see setting the `destfile` property having an effect on where the execution data file is being created).

However, the created `jacoco.exec` file was always empty for me (like also mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/9Atzd4Kq0NU/6FeYd_3jkL4J)), probably because JaCoCo only writes the execution data [at JVM termination](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html), but Android's Dalvik VM does not terminate when the app stops.

The way we currently solve this is to explicitly call

```
org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT.getAgent().getExecutionData(false)
```

and write the returned byte array to a file when our custom test runner finishes.

Comment: Any updates for packaging jacoco-agent.properties into the APK with Gradle?

Comment: Why would you want to supply that file with Gradle? With Gradle, JaCoCo coverage works out of the box, just set `testCoverageEnabled` to `true` for your build type, see e.g. [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/app/build.gradle#L42).

Comment: Would I be correct if I said that it works "out of the box" only for unit tests?

Comment: I works out of the box for both [unit tests](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) (the `test` sourceSet) and functional tests (the `androidTest` sourceSet).

Comment: Alright. Here's my situation: appium as well as manual tests need coverage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182667/packaging-jacoco-agent-properties-into-an-apk-so-it-can-be-read