# Install resource file into root of apk

Tags: android, gradle

When you use a jar as a dependency, any files in the jar root are put into the generated apk's root. Meanwhile, if I *just* have my android project, and I want to put files in the root, I can't! I have to put files in `res/assets` or `res/raw`, which won't do the trick for me.

I'm using a library internal to the company, and it expects a filename for something in the top-level of the produced artifact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With old android projects (the ones that use `ant`, etc), put your resource files in `/resources` (not `/res`) to ensure that they aren't touched by `aapt` and are put in the root.

For new android projects (ones using `gradle`), put these resources in `src/main/resources`

Comment: I was having issues figuring this out, and there didn't seem to be any information online, so I figured adding it to Stackoverflow would help future internetters