# packaging jacoco-agent.properties into an APK so it can be read?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, code-coverage, jacoco

Here's my situation:

**Background**

- I am investigating code-coverage for our Android app. The app is built with Gradle and Android Studio.
- I need code-coverage reports in two situations: during manual tests, and during automated tests built with our sizeable Appium suite.
- I need to get a proof-of-concept out *fast* (isn't that always the case?) so I haven't had the chance to do thorough R&D. So please forgive any ignorance I display :)
- I have access to the app source, but have little knowledge of the moving parts.
- I have investigated JaCoCo and Emma. This question pertains to JaCoCo.
- Given that we need coverage for Appium and manual tests, I believe offline-instrumentation with JaCoCo is what I need.

**Progress Made**

- I used [the JaCoCo plugin page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) and [the Android Tools page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) and could configure build.gradle properly.
- I have verified that the classes (present in `build\intermediates\classes`) are instrumented with JaCoCo, and are packaged in the APK.
- I wrote a BroadCastReceiver per [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976319/android-gradle-jacoco-offline-instrumentation-for-integration-tests), which will receive the "end coverage" broadcast.

**Problem**

When I run the app manually, I keep seeing errors in the logcat
    W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jacoco.exec: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327112/how-to-supply-jacoco-agent-to-an-android-app) and [the JaCoCo docs](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html) I understand that Jacoco needs to know where to store the `jacoco.exec` file - and that I need to package a jacoco-agent.properties (containing a `destfile` property) with the APK.

I have tried putting jacoco-agent.properties in `assets` - it was packaged into the APK properly, but did not seem to have any effect (i.e Jacoco failed as usual)
I tried putting it inside `res` - it did not get packaged into the APK.
I tried `res/raw` and hit the error about a dash in the filename, as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327112/how-to-supply-jacoco-agent-to-an-android-app).

I am at my wit's end, and would really appreciate help. How do I package jacoco-agent.properties using my Gradle build into the APK, so that JaCoCo will read it?

**Related Questions**

[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327112/how-to-supply-jacoco-agent-to-an-android-app), has an answer from 2013, and it's for Ant, not Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the requirement for executing `Jacoco` working, but you can package a file with the apk pretty easily.  The below code will place the `jacoco-agent.properties` at the root of your apk package.

Make these changes to the `build.gradle` for your app module:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources.includes = [ '**/jacoco-agent.properties' ]
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer so it may be clearer for newbies like me :) Please let me know if my edit was correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I added the code but it did not seem to help. (I unzipped the APK and checked that jacoco-agent.properties did not get packaged). My build.gradle looks like this:     `sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            res.includes = ['**/jacoco-agent.properties']
        }`

Comment: @Vish, Your close I see you specified `... res.includes = ['**/jacoco-agent.properties']` The `res` points to the android `Resources` not the Plain Old Java includes which is `resources.includes = ['**/jacoco-agent.properties']`  Note the `res` vs `resources`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am fast realizing that I need a crash lesson on Android development with gradle. Will try this and let you know.

Comment: This didn't work for me nor with 0.8.3, nor with 0.8.5. Does it work for you exactly like this that is written in answer @JBirdVegas ? Where exactly did you put jacoco-agent.properties?